# How to implement ota update for rockchip AOSP ROM?

Tags: android-source, ota

I am gonna implement ota-update system on AOSP for rockchip. This is source code repo - https://github.com/rockchip-android
Actually, my ROM has a few customized parts, but almost similar to the above AOSP.
I would like someone to let me know if it is possible to implement ota-update with the source code, and ideally give me valuable tips such as references, or step-by-step guide for that if it's possible.
My ROM is based on Android 5.0 lollipop.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Check you BSP tree, there should be an app called **RKUpdateService** ( *vendor/rockchip/common/apps/RKUpdateServic*e ).

This is the app that checks for OTA images in a server, downloads and installs them.
By default, the url is defined with **ro.product.ota.host** prop, but you can modify the whole process.

Server side, there is a Java app which you deploy in Apache Tomcat instance.
If you don't have this, contact your Rockchip representative.
Alternatively, you can develop your own server code, since it doesn't do anything fancy, it just provides a way to return some specific OTA zip file when the device requests it.